# Untying Cygwin from cmd

Tags: shell, cmake, terminal, cygwin

I have both CMake 3.18.1 and Cygwin installed on my local machine. However, every time I try to use CMake within the command prompt it keeps bombing. I have a feeling that Cygwin's own built-in version of CMake is messing with things. Is there any way to untie Cygwin's access just to the command prompt so that I can use CMake there?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the exact command you are using, and the error message, in text, not a screenshot, please?

Comment: Is Cygwin in your PATH when you run Cmake ? If yes have you tried removing it ? If not, why do you think Cygwin is interfering ?